# Product list per product or per variable?

Tags: e-commerce, product-details, catalog

I have a product X that has a range of variables, from 100 - 2000 kg.

Is it a better UX to display one product as 'Product X (100 - 2000 kg)' or individual products with each an own product page, ex. 'Product X 100 kg', 'Product X 200 kg'.

Do they need to be displayed as individual products in the product list? Or is one product good enough and you then select the variable. Pictures will differ per product, and only small specifications are different.

Since products should be compared, individual products need to exist.

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely go for one product 'Product X (100 - 2000 kg)'. Multiple repetitions of essentially the same product (but in different quantities) will just **get in the way** of the other products you want to showcase on the lister page. The more 'quantities' you have, the worse it is.

Consider an e-commerce site for fashion. They sell all kinds of T-shirts, and each design is available in different sizes. They might indicate the available sizes (S - 3XL) on the lister page, but I've never seen all sizes listed apart from each other; you get to choose the size either on the product detail page, or in some kind of popover/tooltip when you hover over the actual product.